# Show all endpoints in Firebase Dashboard when using Express

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

How can I create a function that allows me to create a pretty URL like.

> GET users/ID/someResource/ID/subResource/ID

I could create a GET URL GetSomeResourceByUser, that not pretty, I prefer the first URL.

I've tried exporting an express app where I did this

```
app.get("/users/:uid/someResource/:sid/subResource/:rid", (request, response) => {
    // ...
});

const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
module.exports = {
    api
}
```

The problem is all my endpoints end up as one single endpoint in the Firebase Cloud Functions Dashboard called api and I'm not able to see the statistics for each HTTPS action "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE".

Is there a way to create pretty URL's while keeping access to Firebase Cloud Functions Dashboard statistics?

Comment: It's not possible without creating separate apps registered as different exports.

Comment: Allright, I'm concerned about multiple Express apps would increase code complexity and response time. I've taken a look at Firebase Hosting Rewrite, Do you recommend me creating a rewrite rule for "/users/:uid/someResource/:sid/subResource/:rid" to a specific Cloud Function?

Comment: I'm currently going with exporting a single express app, my concern is whether it affects performance and how I can measure my API to calculate costs regarding runtime, CPU seconds, memory GB seconds. Per endpoint.